# Puzzle on the second stack in postfix calculator

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm reading "TCPL" recently.There exist a classic case "postfix calculator" in section 4.3. I have a question on the case:
See the case code(copy from the book):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

#define MAXOP 100
#define NUMBER '0'
#define MAXVAL 100 /* maxmium depth of val stack */
#define BUFFSIZE 100


int sp = 0;
double val[MAXVAL];

int bufp = 0; /* next free size in buf*/
char buf[BUFFSIZE]; /* buffer in ungetch */


int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);
int getop(char []);
void push(double);
double pop(void);

int main()
{
    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[MAXOP];

    while ((type = getop(s)) != EOF) {
        switch (type) {
            case NUMBER:
                push(atof(s));
                break;
            case '+':
                push(pop() + pop());
                break;
            case '*':
                push(pop() * pop());
                break;
            case '-':
                op2 = pop();
                push(pop() - op2);
                break;
            case '/':
                op2 = pop();
                if (op2 != 0.0) {
                    push(pop() / op2);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("error: zero divisor. \n");
                }
                break;
            default:
                printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


/* push: push value f onto value stack */
void push(double f)
{
    if (sp < MAXVAL) {
        val[sp++] = f;
    }
    else {
        printf("error: stack full, can't push.\n");
    }
}


/* pop: pop and return value on the top of the stack */
double pop(void)
{
    if (sp > 0) {
        return val[--sp]; 
    }
    else {
        printf("error: stack empty.\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}



/* getop: get next character or numeric operand */
int getop(char s[])
{
    int i, c;

    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t') {
        ;
    }
    s[1] = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.' ) { /* operator */
        return c;
    }
    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c)) {               /* collect integer part */
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch())) {
            ;
        }
    }
    if (c == '.') {                 /* collect fraction part */
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch())) {
            ;
        }
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF) {
        ungetch(c);
    }
    return NUMBER;
}


/* getch:  get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
int getch(void)
{
    return (bufp > 0)? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}


/* ungetch: push character back on input */
void ungetch(int c)
{
    if (bufp >= BUFFSIZE) {
        printf("ungetch: too many characters in buufer.\n");
    }
    else {
        buf[bufp++] = c;
    }
}
```

There is a global char array `buf`, It is like a stack and the last two function are to 'pop' and 'push' on `buf`.

**My question is in which case does the stack `buf` contains more than one element?**

The only chance can the `ungetch()` be called is in function `getop()`, however in `getop()` the function `getch()` is called at least once.

Comment: *"in which case does the stack buf contains more than one element?"* - immediately before any binary operator is encountered. There had better be at least two operands on the stack or your postfix expression is ill-defined.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the meaning of `buf`. `buf` is **not** a stack, it is just a buffer for `stdin`. `val` is the stack.

Comment: `buf` is a lexical pushback buffer for the cases where the scanner overruns the current token. It should never contain more thane *character,* and if the scanning was better written it wouldn't be necessary. @EOF

Comment: @user207421 Right, *technically* it is FIFO, so you could say that it is a stack. Not sure what you mean by "overruns the current token". It allows the parser to have lookahead. Because this parser is simple, it only needs a single character lookahead, so there is no reason for the buffer to be larger than 1 character.

Comment: @EOF Since there is no reason for the buffer to be larger than 1 character, Why does the author add the condition `if (bufp >= BUFFSIZE) {...}` and set the `BUFFSIZE` to 100?

Comment: _getch_ can be `getchar()` and _ungetch_ can be `ungetc(c, stdin);`, see my answer

Comment: @FrankWalker If I were to speculate, I'd say it's to show reusable code that can be used for parsers with larger lookaheads. On the other hand, the code should not be reused in this form today, as it really isn't very good.

Comment: I'm clear now, Ty!

Comment: @EOF It allows the *scanner* to have lookahead, of one *character*. There is no parser lookahead required in an expression grammar. It is not a FIFO but a LIFO, and a LIFO *is* a stack. However, as only one character is required, it is over-implemented as a stack. And any grammar that requires more than one *token* of lookahead can rewritten with lookahead of one token, if it satisfies certain conditions, as this one does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is in which case does the stack buf contains more than one element?

never, *buf* can be just a char, it is only used to memorize the char placed just after a number to not lost it

The code can be modified to not use it :

```
/* getch:  get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
int getch(void)
{
    return getchar();
}


/* ungetch: push character back on input */
void ungetch(int c)
{
  ungetc(c, stdin);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc pf.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 2 3 4 + + +
    10
```

---

Or using the fact only one char can be saved :

```
int SavedChar = EOF;

/* getch:  get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
int getch(void)
{
  if (SavedChar == EOF)
    return getchar();

  int r = SavedChar;

  SavedChar = EOF;

  return r;
}

/* ungetch: push character back on input */
void ungetch(int c)
{
  SavedChar = c;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc pf.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1 2 3 4 + + +
    10
```

Comment: I'm not sure on the history here, but is it possible that the code originates from before standardization of `ungetc()`?

Comment: @EOF I really don't know,  I use _ungetc_ since age

Comment: My purpose is to make clear what exactly happened in  function `ungetch()` or  `ungetc()` rather than making code simpler to use:) Anyway,  Ty for your answer.

Comment: @FrankWalker only one char need to be saved (unget), I edited y answer with an alternative solution

Comment: @bruno I thought so, just the condition `if (bufp >= BUFFSIZE) {...}` puzzled me.

Comment: @FrankWalker that and the array declaration/use are useless, see my new editing

Comment: @bruno yes, your code is better than the original code.